# Fetch from Cache Jolt Spec with Expression language and putting attribute doesn't calculate Expression language

Tags: apache-nifi, el, jolt

I have stored Jolt Spec which has expression language

```
[
 {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
        "id": "${UUID()}"
  
      }
  }
]
```

I have stored this in DB and fetching and putting it into distributed map cache and then fetching from cache and putting as attribute of the flow file attribute and using JoltTransformJson with nifi version 1.13 but it is not evaluating the EL and the result is coming as same

```
{
  "id" : "${UUID()}"
}
```

The processor mentioned that it supports Attribute. Am I missing something?

Comment: if the JOLT spec is in an attribute called 'myAttr' and you use '${myAttr}' inside the JOLT Spec field to get the value of your attribute, then the EL being evaluated is '${myAttr}' - not any EL inside the value

Comment: The problem is when you load from DB or Cache it's not evaluated. I ended up using like this ${commandSpec:evaluateELString()} and it's working. Here "CommandSpec" is the attribute loaded from DB or Cache which has defined Spec